# how to program wait and continue in this bash script

Tags: bash, wait, continue

I have two shell scripts say A and B. I need to run A in the background and run B in the foreground till A finishes its execution in the background. I need to repeat this process for couple of runs, hence once A finishes, I need to suspend current iteration and move to next iteration.

Rough idea is like this:

```
for((i=0; i< 10; i++))  
do  
./A.sh &

for ((c=0; c< C_MAX; c++))  
do  
./B.sh  
done

continue

done
```

how do I use '`wait`' and '`continue`' so that B runs as many times while A is in the background and the entire process moves to next iteration once A finishes

Answer (score 3):

Use the PID of the current background process:

```
./A.sh &
while ps -p $! >/dev/null; do
    ./B.sh
done
```

Comment: Wil this remove the need for 'continue' and move to next iteration ?

Comment: @thiton Nice stuff (+1). Please take a look at my answer. I believe it was asked a little different logic but your wait-continue while loop is really great.

Answer (score 1):

I am just translating your rough idea into bash scripting.
The core idea to implement the wait-continue mechanism (`while ps -p $A_PID >/dev/null; do...`) is taken from @thiton who posted an answer earlier to your question.

```
for i in `seq 0 10`
do
  ./A.sh &
  A_PID=$!
  for i in `seq 0 $C_MAX`
  do
    ./B.sh
  done
  while ps -p $A_PID >/dev/null; do
      sleep 1
  done
done
```